# Python - why does this for loop only print 1 letter?

Tags: python

```
def caesar(plaintext,shift):  
    alphabet=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]  

    #Create our substitution dictionary  
    dic={}  
    for i in range(0,len(alphabet)):  
        dic[alphabet[i]]=alphabet[(i+shift)%len(alphabet)]  

    #Convert each letter of plaintext to the corrsponding  
    #encrypted letter in our dictionary creating the cryptext  
    ciphertext=("")  
    for l in plaintext.lower():  
            if l in dic:  
                l=dic[l]  
                ciphertext+=l
            return ciphertext  

#Example useage  
plaintext="the cat sat on the mat"  
print "Plaintext:", plaintext  
print "Cipertext:", (caesar(plaintext,29))
```

The cipertext prints just one letter, instead of printing the 'plaintext' variable in caesar shift. I want it to print the whole sentence.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because your `return ciphertext` is indented wrong. You return from the first iteration of the for loop. (Indentation matters a lot in Python!)

```
    for l in plaintext.lower():  
            if l in dic:  
                l=dic[l]  
                ciphertext+=l
            return ciphertext  # Indented to match level of `if`.
```

Fix it to.

```
    for l in plaintext.lower():  
        if l in dic:  
            l=dic[l]  
            ciphertext+=l
    return ciphertext
```

**Couple of Pointers**

1. Instead of listing out all alphabets in your code, you can just set `alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase`.
2. You don't need a variable to store `dic[l]`, just do `ciphertext += dic[l]`.

Comment: Thanks I got it working now. But one more problem. The caesar doesn't have spaces, it's just one string of letters like this: wkhdwvdwrqwkhpdw

Comment: That is because it fails the criteria `if l in dic`, you need to make an `else` statement for such cases where you append the element anyway. (I don't think you shift the punctuations in the shift).

Answer (score 3):

do it better with string.translate :)

```
import string
def caesar(plaintext,shift):  
    alphabet=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    alphabet_shifted = alphabet[shift:]+alphabet[:shift]
    tab =    string.maketrans("".join(alphabet),"".join(alphabet_shifted))
    return plaintext.translate(tab)
```

Comment: +1, This is awesome! Put alphabet as `string.ascii_lowercase`, then you don't need `"".join(...)`.

Comment: yes I agree but this way it would work with whatever alphabet you wanted to define ... as a list or tuple

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the indents for the return statement:

```
for l in plaintext.lower():  
    if l in dic:  
       l=dic[l]  
       ciphertext+=l
    # <-- if you return here, then you will loop only once.      
return ciphertext
```